# Polars get count of events prior to "this" event, but within given duration

Tags: python-polars

I have been struggling with creating a feature, a counter that counts number of events prior to each event, where each prior event should have occurred within a given duration (dt). I know how to do it for all previous events, it is easy by using `cumsum` and `over` of the given column. But, if  I want to do this with only events within e.g last 2 days, how do I do that ??

Below is how I do it (the wrong way) with `cumsum`.

```py
import polars as pl
from datetime import date

df = pl.DataFrame(
    data = {
            "Event":["Rain","Sun","Rain","Sun","Rain","Sun","Rain","Sun"],
            "Date":[
                date(2022,1,1),
                date(2022,1,2),
                date(2022,1,2),
                date(2022,1,3),
                date(2022,1,3),
                date(2022,1,5),
                date(2022,1,5),
                date(2022,1,8)
            ]
    }
)

df.select(
    pl.col("Date").cumcount().over("Event").alias("cum_sum")
)
```

outputting

```py
shape: (8, 3)
┌───────┬────────────┬─────────┐
│ Event ┆ Date       ┆ cum_sum │
│ ---   ┆ ---        ┆ ---     │
│ str   ┆ date       ┆ u32     │
╞═══════╪════════════╪═════════╡
│ Rain  ┆ 2022-01-01 ┆ 0       │
│ Sun   ┆ 2022-01-02 ┆ 0       │
│ Rain  ┆ 2022-01-02 ┆ 1       │
│ Sun   ┆ 2022-01-03 ┆ 1       │
│ Rain  ┆ 2022-01-03 ┆ 2       │
│ Sun   ┆ 2022-01-05 ┆ 2       │
│ Rain  ┆ 2022-01-05 ┆ 3       │
│ Sun   ┆ 2022-01-08 ┆ 3       │
└───────┴────────────┴─────────┘
```

What I would like to output is this:

```py
shape: (8, 3)
┌───────┬────────────┬─────────┐
│ Event ┆ Date       ┆ cum_sum │
│ ---   ┆ ---        ┆ ---     │
│ str   ┆ date       ┆ u32     │
╞═══════╪════════════╪═════════╡
│ Rain  ┆ 2022-01-01 ┆ 0       │
│ Sun   ┆ 2022-01-02 ┆ 0       │
│ Rain  ┆ 2022-01-02 ┆ 1       │
│ Sun   ┆ 2022-01-03 ┆ 1       │
│ Rain  ┆ 2022-01-03 ┆ 2       │
│ Sun   ┆ 2022-01-05 ┆ 1       │
│ Rain  ┆ 2022-01-05 ┆ 1       │
│ Sun   ┆ 2022-01-08 ┆ 0       │
└───────┴────────────┴─────────┘
```

(Preferably, a solution that scales somewhat well..)

Thanks

Tried this without success

Comment: I think https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.groupby_dynamic.html is the method you are looking for. Probably best to have it return the boundaries when trying it out, so you have a good understanding of what is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try a `groupby_rolling` for this.

```py
(
    df
    .groupby_rolling(
        index_column="Date",
        period="2d",
        by="Event",
        closed='both',
    )
    .agg([
        pl.count() - 1
    ])
    .sort(["Date", "Event"], reverse=[False, True])
)
```

```
shape: (8, 3)
┌───────┬────────────┬───────┐
│ Event ┆ Date       ┆ count │
│ ---   ┆ ---        ┆ ---   │
│ str   ┆ date       ┆ u32   │
╞═══════╪════════════╪═══════╡
│ Rain  ┆ 2022-01-01 ┆ 0     │
│ Sun   ┆ 2022-01-02 ┆ 0     │
│ Rain  ┆ 2022-01-02 ┆ 1     │
│ Sun   ┆ 2022-01-03 ┆ 1     │
│ Rain  ┆ 2022-01-03 ┆ 2     │
│ Sun   ┆ 2022-01-05 ┆ 1     │
│ Rain  ┆ 2022-01-05 ┆ 1     │
│ Sun   ┆ 2022-01-08 ┆ 0     │
└───────┴────────────┴───────┘
```

We subtract one in the `agg` because we do not want to count the current event, only prior events.  (The sort at the end is just to order the rows to match the original data.)

Comment: There is no need to subtract one to the event counts if you pass `closed="left"` instead of `closed="both"`